# How to access a specific reducer in react-testing-library

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, redux, react-testing-library

I've been trying to implement unit testing with react using the react-testing-library

I want to test my login component that use **useSelector** and **useDispatch** hooks from react-redux

The problem is that when I use this function to pass the store to in my login.test.js is not recognizing the reducer and show me this error:

```
 An error occurred while selecting the store state: Cannot read property 'isLoading' of undefined.

 const isLoadingAuth = useSelector(state => state.Auth.isLoading);
```

I use combineReducers in my store (the app has a lot of reducers) in order to access in that specific reducer "Auth" but I don't know how to use them in my login.test.js

How can I access to my Auth reducer in my login.test.js file?

This is my login.jsx

```
const LoginForm = () => {
  const [values, setValues] = useState({ email: "", password: "" });
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  function handleChange(e) {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setValues({ ...values, [name]: value });
  }

  function submitData(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    dispatch(actions.AuthUser(values));
  }

  const isLoadingAuth = useSelector(state => state.Auth.isLoading);
  const error = useSelector(state => state.Auth.err);
  const isAuthSucess = useSelector(state => state.Auth.isAuthSuccess);

  if (isAuthSuccess) {
    <Redirect to="/dashboard" />;
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={submitData}>
          <Input
            label="Email"
            name="email"
            value={values.email}
            change={handleChange}
          />
          <Input
            label="Password"
            name="password"
            type="password"
            value={values.password}
            change={handleChange}
          />
          <div>
            <button>Entrar</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

My AuthReducer.js

```
import * as actionTypes from "../actions/Auth/types";
import { updateObject } from "../store/utility";

export const initalState = {
  authData: null,
  isLoading: false,
  isAuthSuccess: null,
  err: null
};

const authStart = state => {
  return updateObject(state, {
    isLoading: true,
    err: null
  });
};

const authFail = (state, action) => {
  return updateObject(state, {
    isLoading: false,
    err: action.err
  });
};

const auth = (state, action) => {
  return updateObject(state, {
    isLoading: false,
    authData: action.authData,
    isAuthSuccess: true
  });
};

export function reducer(state = initalState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case actionTypes.START_AUTH_REQ: {
      return authStart(state, action);
    }
    case actionTypes.FAIL_AUTH_REQ: {
      return authFail(state, action);
    }
    case actionTypes.AUTH: {
      return auth(state, action);
    }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default reducer;
```

And my Login.test.js

```
import React from "react";
import { createStore, combineReducers } from "redux";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { render, cleanup, fireEvent } from "@testing-library/react";
import rootReducer from "../../../../reducers";
import "@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect";
import LoginForm from "./Form";


function renderWithRedux(
  ui,
  {
    initialState,
    store = createStore(combineReducers(rootReducer, initialState))
  } = {}
) {
  return {
    ...render(<Provider store={store}>{ui}</Provider>),
    // adding `store` to the returned utilities to allow us
    // to reference it in our tests (just try to avoid using
    // this to test implementation details).
    store
  };
}

test("can render with redux with custom initial state", () => {
  const { getByTestId, getByText } = renderWithRedux(<LoginForm />, {
    initialState: { isLoading: false }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your initial state is for you entire store so needs to match the structure of your root reducer:

```
test("can render with redux with custom initial state", () => {
  const { getByTestId, getByText } = renderWithRedux(<LoginForm />, {
    initialState: { Auth: { isLoading: false } }
  });
});
```

Comment: Hmm, not sure if this the cause but it looks like your call to `createStore` is slightly incorrect - `initialState` should be passed to `createStore` not `combineReducers` - so `store = createStore(combineReducers(rootReducer), initialState)` That said I don't think that should be causing the issue. Can you try updating your selector to `const isLoadingAuth = useSelector(state => {console.log(state); return state.Auth.isLoading;});` so you can see what value you are getting for your store state?

Answer (score 0):

I know it is a late reply but might help someone.

The problem with the above code is that it is using combineReducer correctly but passing state of AuthReducer only.

The combineReducer is expecting a consolidated state. For example:

```html
const state = {
  auth: initialState,
  app: {
    temp: {
      // Some state
    }
  }
}

function renderWithRedux(ui: any, state: any) {
  const store = createStore(rootReducer, state)
  return {
    ...render(<Provider store={ store } > { ui } < /Provider>),
        store,
    }
}


test('can render with redux with custom initial state', () => {
    const { getByTestId, getByText } = renderWithRedux(<LoginForm />, {
        ...state,
        auth: {
            ...initialState, loading: true
        }
    });
});
```